# login returns error invalid credentials even the given credentials is correct

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to modify the default authentication to tailor my needs. I have this requirements like a user should be able to login using either user name or email but it always returns invalid credentials error even if the given credentials are correct, please refer to the code below:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to log the user into the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        // return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        if(filter_var($request->username_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){
            return $request->only('email', 'password');
        }else{
            return $request->only('username', 'password');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
        return response()->json([ 'message' => 'authenticated']);
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'username_email';
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

Inside `credentials()`, I check if its an username or email first and then return the corresponding database column, but it looks like it doesn't work at all. Any ideas, help please?

Answer (score 1):

Your method:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```

With `username()` returning `username_email` seems incoherent. I think what you looking for is [`required_without_all`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required-without):

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required_without_all:email|string',
        'email' => 'required_without_all:username|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```

So `username` will be required when `email` is not present and vice versa.